# Ubuntu 18.04 - Very slow boot times and multiple systemd failures / connection timed out errors

Tags: boot, 18.04, network-manager, systemd

After restarting my 18.04 server I'm getting very slow boot times (takes upwards of 5-15 minutes to be able to log in) and multiple "systemd" failures.

Here's what I'm seeing error wise:

```
systemd[1]: Failed to get initial list of names: Connection timed out
systemd[1]: Failed to to set up API bus: Connection timed out
systemd[1]: Error occured during D-Bus APIs: Connection timed out
systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service: Connection timed out
```

For reference here are

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Sep  6 14:06 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search blacklab.ddns.net

$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp8s0
iface enp8s0 inet dhcp
```

Any ideas how how to fix/troubleshoot this?  Thanks

**UPDATE**:

Also noticing slow `sudo apt-get update/upgrade` with errors such as these:

```
Err:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable/main i386 Packages                                                                                                         
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 2607:f8b0:4007:800::200e 443]

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/coral-edgetpu-stable/main/binary-i386/Packages  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 2607:f8b0:4007:800::200e 443]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Those are not network errors. Those are internal socket failures. Try a couple reboots to see if the errors go away on their own. I have seen those before on hardware failures - faulty motherboard. However that is just one data point - may be many possible causes.

Comment: I've tried a number of reboots without success :(.  Thanks for the comment though ... I'll be hoping its not something with the hardware.